# What are Borromean signatures?

Tags: ringct, cryptography, borromean

For more background info visit [GitHub](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1413) or [Bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1077994.0)

It looks like borromean signatures are going to be replacing schnorr signatures in the RingCT hardfork. What does this mean for Monero and RingCT performance etc? thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I happened to have read Greg Maxwell's [paper](https://github.com/Blockstream/borromean_paper/blob/master/borromean_draft_0.01_9ade1e49.pdf) recently, so here I try to lay down my interpretation in a bit abstract manner:

Before talking about the Borromean scheme, let us recapitulate the current ring signature scheme described in [MRL-0005](https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0005.pdf).
The signature data looks like:

```
R = (M, {P_1,...,P_n}, c_1, {r_1,...,r_n})
```

where `M` is some message's hash, each `P_i` is a pubkey in the ring, and `c_1` and `r_i` are scalars (the key image part is omitted here for brevity).
Any participant in the network verifies this signature as follows:

```
L_1 = c_1 P + r_1 G
c_2 = H(M, L_1)               // H(...) is a hash function
...
L_i = c_i P + r_i G
c_{i+1} = H(M, L_i)
...
L_n = c_n P + r_n G
```

Finally, the signature is confirmed as valid if `c_1 = H(M, L_n)`.
I skip explaining how such a signature can be generated only by a true signer knowing the secret key `x` of one of the pubkeys `P_s = xG` for some secret index `1<=s<=n`.

A transaction generally has multiple inputs, say `m` inputs, so you create a ring signature for each input:

```
R^j = (M, {P_1^j,...,P_n^j}, c_1^j, {r_1^j,...,r_n^j})
```

for `j=1,...,m`.
Note that the signature contains `m*(n+1)` scalars of `c`'s and `r`'s.
Note also that such a concatenation of multiple ring signatures is needed for RingCT when proving that a given committed amount is within a certain range (called [range proof](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/)).

The goal of the Borromean ring signature scheme is to reduce the signature size by making all `c_1^j`'s identical:

```
c_1^1 = c_1^2 = ... = c_1^m
      = c_1
```

so that the number of scalars stored in the signature becomes `m*n+1`.

To achieve this goal, the scheme modifies the verification rule a little bit.
As before, the verifier computes for each `j=1,...,m`:

```
c_1 -> L_1^j -> c_2^j -> ... -> c_n^j -> L_n^j
```

and the signature is confirmed valid if the following holds:

```
c_1 = H(M, L_n^1, ..., L_n^m)
```

The signature generation can be implemented by adding some small modifications to the original scheme (I believe).

Comment: So basically that would decrease transaction size right? Verification faster etc?

Comment: Yes, the signature size (included in the tx data) becomes smaller. The verification time will also become slightly faster, technically speaking, since a single hash function call is needed for `c_1` (as opposed to `m` calls for `c_1^j`).

Comment: What sort of impact will this have on ringct transaction size?  Is it a constant reduction, or is it proportional to the mixin?

Comment: It's inverse proportional to mixin; with `m` inputs and `n-1` mixin, the signature size changes from `m*(n+1)` to `m*n+1`, so the reduction ratio would be `((m*n+m)-(m*n+1)) / (m*n+m) = (m-1) / (m*n+m)`. For example, with `m=3, n=5`, the reduction is 11%. The real impact would be for the range proof where `m=64, n=2` and the reduction is 33%.

Comment: Note that it's not an effective size change at all. Borromean replaced ASNL in the Monero codebase, which had a problem in its proof, but was the same size. It would be a size reduction if it were replacing certain other types.

Comment: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/what-was-the-problem-with-asnl-forgery @Luigi is this an adequate answer for why ASNL was changed? Or are there other considerations?  Also, thanks, almost glossed over your comment and missed the reason for the change.