# Looking for a paper describing Monero

Tags: cryptonote

I want to learn about Monero in good detail. Unfortunately I am not able to find any good and complete resource which described how this cryptocurrency works.

Most of the papers I found are analyzing the anonymity of Monero. On the homepage of Monero I found [this](https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0005.pdf) resource. However this is not explaining how Monero works, it is explaining Group signatures which are used by Monero. Still its not explaining how everything works together.

Comment: Have you read the [cryptonote whitepaper](https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf)?

Comment: @assylias Hello, is this really the paper describing monero? I heard that monero is using ringCT and the cryptonote protocol where used in older versions. This is true?

Comment: And once you finished the crypto note whitepaper, have a look et the [Monero Research Lab's publications](https://lab.getmonero.org).

Comment: @Maxithi Thanks, one question: Are Cryptonote and RingCT working together or did RingCT replace Cryptonote?

Comment: RingCT did not replace Cryptonote. I'm not sure if it replaced part of it but one thing is for sure: The Cryptonote WP is still the foundation of Monero

Comment: Hello, serhack here. Would you like to have a good resource in order to learn more about monero? The Monero community is helping a lot in order to compose a good and solid resource called Mastering Monero.

Answer (score 5):

Since Monero is based on the CryptoNote protocol, you should take a look [at this resource](https://cryptonote.org/inside) and the standards [here](https://cryptonote.org/standards)

Answer (score 5):

The most detailed instruction about RingCT I had saw.

https://cryptoservices.github.io/cryptography/2017/07/21/Sigs.html

This describes ring signature, Pedersen commitment and range proof together and clearly.

Answer (score 5):

An excellent overview of most aspects of Monero (excluding subaddresses and bulletproofs) is here: https://github.com/kurtmagnus/Monero-RCT-report/blob/master/main.pdf

Learn about Elliptic Curve Cryptography here: https://steemit.com/monero/@luigi1111/understanding-monero-cryptography-privacy-introduction

Learn about Monero's proof of work algorithm, stealth addresses and Monero's original ring signatures (LSAG) in the cryptonote white paper https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf

Learn about how confidential transactions hide transaction amounts (including what range proofs are) here: https://people.xiph.org/~greg/confidential_values.txt

Learn about blockchain transaction structures here: https://cryptonote.org/standards/

Learn about the MLSAG upgrade to Monero's ring signatures here: https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0005.pdf

Learn about Bulletproofs, which will be replacing Monero's existing range proofs, here: https://github.com/AdamISZ/from0k2bp/blob/master/testzkp.pdf and here: https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1066.pdf

Learn about ring signatures in a more general sense here: http://diyhpl.us/~bryan/papers2/bitcoin/Borromean%20ring%20signatures.pdf

Learn about subaddresses here: https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0006.pdf

See all of the Monero Research Lab publications here: https://lab.getmonero.org/

Answer (score 4):

A self-contained and comprehensive description of the crypto of RCT transactions can be found under
https://github.com/kurtmagnus/Monero-RCT-report/blob/master/main.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much, I found this pdf document very useful as it is comprehensive and complete. For me its really hard to understand how which parts of the original CryptoNote paper and the document you posted are being used and how they are working together. E.g. How relevant is section 4.4. one-time ring signatures in the Cryptonote paper? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I've also noticed a certain lack of comprehensive papers / documentation. I believe that [monero's git repo](https://github.com/monero-project/monero) has recently outpaced some of the whitepapers, and now is a good time to start analyzing the code, and building documentation / wikis.

[This paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1098) is mentioned many times in the source. Regarding RingCT, there's also [this helpful QA](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/can-someone-walk-me-through-a-simple-example-to-explain-how-ringct-works).

Comment: The problem with this paper is that it contains some errors. Also, there are divergences with the code, in that multi-input transactions use a different scheme.
Check https://github.com/kurtmagnus/Monero-RCT-report/blob/master/main.pdf
It describes signature schemes and links them to the actual implementation