# How is the used Pedersen commitment kept secret?

Tags: ringct

I understand one can have two commitments `P` and `Q`, and show the world that `P - Q = 0` - communicating the commitment to only the recipient. In fact, it can be done with many input commitments `P1 ... Pn`. However, how do the other commitments remain hidden?

The user can take `P1 ... Pn`, when he really only knows the commitment key for `P1`, and then generate output `Q1 ... Qn` with `sum(P)` = `sum(Q)`. However, doesn't that invalidate the random `P2 ... Pn` he was trying to mixin with? They still need to be able to spend their commitments using the private keys they know for the old `P`s.

I just don't really understand how Pedersen Commitments integrate with mixins.

<del>**Bounty:**</del>

Under the original scheme, We have the following:

1. Take N input transactions that hold the same amount of Monero
2. Prove I have the private key for one of them using Ring Signatures
3. Provide a keyImage that's never been used before, and prove that it is equal to privateKey * Hash(PublicKey) for one of the N transactions. This is done without revealing which privateKey was used.
4. Provide M output transactions, signed to prove that you approve of them, such that the sum of the output amounts is equal to the common amount used in the input transactions.

The total state changes resulting from steps 1-4 is that One KeyImage is stored and cannot be used again, and M output transactions are stored for later usage.

(Of course, the proofs are stored too but are never used ever again except for new nodes downloading the blockchain. Thus, I do not include them in "state changes")

Now, my final question: How does this work with Pedersen Commitments? What exactly *is* the input->output relation for a transaction under RingCT, along with state changes? I want to be able to read it in a format equivalent to the step-by-step format I gave for pre-RingCT transactions. Bounty for whoever does this :)

I ask this because, if each Pedersen Commitment holds a different value, how could it ever be so that the Pedersen Commitment remains secret? Isn't it obvious which one I used? If I consumed several commitments, then what happens to them if I didn't own them? I just don't understand. I would like a more explicit explanation.

## <del>UPDATE</del>

Everything written under "Bounty" can be ignored. Back to the original question, regarding mixins. I understand most of it now, due to "[Can someone walk me through a simple example to explain how RingCT works?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/can-someone-walk-me-through-a-simple-example-to-explain-how-ringct-works?rq=1)". However, this explanation does not discuss how the Pedersen Commitment proved is not used twice. I understand it's possible to introduce a second key image to prevent double usage of the pedersen commitment, but is this the most space-efficient method? What does Monero use? (Bounty is redesignated for the answerer of this question.)

## Update 2

Using a key image on Pedersen wouldn't solve the problem, because I could use a pedersen from someone else's transaction since I know the pedersen key for any transactions I send out. I could then steal their pedersen commitment. However, the realization is simple. I left it in a comment to "[Can someone walk me through a simple example to explain how RingCT works?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/can-someone-walk-me-through-a-simple-example-to-explain-how-ringct-works?rq=1)"

Answer (score 3):

A commitment is published publicly for every output created in a transaction, and thus every input in a transaction also has a known commitment.

Commitments are public. It's only the amount and blinding factor that are kept private between the creator of the output (sender) and the output's recipient.

The MLSAG ring signature proves that there is a set of inputs and outputs such that `P - Q = zG` where `zG` is the commitment to zero, and only someone that knows all the blinding factors can prove knowledge of `z` (and the signature proves that without disclosing the value of `z` publicly).

Comment: But wouldn't the blinding factors be unknown for mixins? I'm not understanding the mixin part of it. What does "Proves that there is _a_ set" mean? Does that mean "Proves there exists at least one subset"? I'm not even sure what the exact inputs and outputs are of a transaction using ringCT, which is also causing confusion. I understand vanilla mixin, but not the commitments part.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone Only the creator and recipient of an output will know the blinding factor for that particular output on the blockchain. That applies whether we're talking about the real input being spent or a decoy/mixin input.

Comment: Is the recipient also given z? Ive mostly seen (P - Q) = 0 and this zG is starting to make more sense. I was wondering, "Well, can't I clearly see which difference is equal to 0?"

Comment: @NicholasPipitone z is the sum of input blinding factors minus the sum of output blinding factors. Since the sender of a transaction owns the inputs and so knows the input blinding factors, and knows the output blinding factors because the sender is deciding those blinding factors, the sender can easily calculate z.

Comment: Okay, but that remains - if mixin is being used doesn't the sender not know all of the blinding factors? I understand the zG part now, which is an interesting addition. Discrete Log blocks the sender from finding a z'G = zG + mH

Comment: @NicholasPipitone When you have a commitment to zero, it's a public key with a private key z. If it were not a commitment to zero, it'd be a public key with private key z+ah, where h is the h in H = hG. But since h is unknowable, the private key for a non-zero commitment is unknowable and thus a non-zero commitment can't be signed for.

Comment: The sender doesn't need to know all of the blinding factors. The sender only needs to know the blinding factors of the real inputs being spent in order to form a valid MLSAG signature. You should read more into MLSAG to find out more.

Comment: I posted a bounty if you want to help answer the question. I still do not understand. What exactly is the set of all inputs of a transaction, and the set of all outputs of a transaction. And, how does the state of the blockchain change as a result?

Comment: I figured it out now. I think the best explanation for my original question is "You generate a new commitment P_2, and then prove you know z s.t. P - P_2 = zG. Thus, the amounts of P and P_2 are equivalent. Then, you use P_2 as your input commitment and create an output commitment O where everyone can verify that O - P_2 = 0"

Answer (score 0):

For the original question:

Say you have a transaction T with commitment P. You generate a new commitment P_2, and then prove you know z s.t. P - P_2 = zG. Thus, the amounts of P and P_2 are equivalent, or else P - P_2 would be equal to yG + (amount1 - amount2)H = zG. Discrete log between G and H prevents you proving that you know that z. Then, you use P_2 as your input commitment and create an output commitment O where everyone can verify that O - P_2 = 0.

<del>You can then use a key image for which pedersen commitment you used, to prevent using the same pedersen commitment twice.</del>

The Pedersen Commitment must be from the same private key that your key image came from, by the nature of the borromean ring signature (Read more here: [Can someone walk me through a simple example to explain how RingCT works?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/can-someone-walk-me-through-a-simple-example-to-explain-how-ringct-works?rq=1)).

Comment: Actually, what's the point of the key image protecting the public key of the transaction anymore? You can just use the commitment in the key image. You dont actually care if you double spend the public key, you only care if you double spend the commitment. Whoops I think I solved it.

Comment: Wait nvm, the sender also knows the pedersen private key so it would be bad if the sender clould kill the image after spending the coin. I still don't know how it works

Comment: "The Pedersen Commitment must be from the same private key that your key image came from". This is not correct, the private key of an output is not related to the blinding factor of any Pedersen Commitment.

Comment: @knaccc Yes, ik, that's not what I meant. I was referring to the note that the Pedersen Commitment must be associated with the private key that you used to generate the signature. In the original CryptoNote algorithm, you check the sum of the "c" values against the hash, so the private key you signed with and the key image you gave could be totally different. Before ringCT, all input amounts were the same, so no one cared. However, with the new algo of hash of i gives a seed for i+1, it means the key image of i cannot be combined with the pedersen commitment of j because it'll break the loop.